# Which is larger, $\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$ or $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}$?

Tags: arithmetic

The clue given by the text is to "use the fact that $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing."

I was able to get the correct answer here by squaring both expressions. But I don't think I made use of the text-prided clue, so am wondering if perhaps I'm missing the "deeper" lesson.

What do you think the author is hinting at?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if the author wanted to use that $\sqrt{x}$ is *concave* rather than increasing - that condition would suffice...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I think a "deeper" lesson here could be had by proving the inequality using only the fact that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is concave (and that $\frac{3+5}{2} = \frac{2+6}{2}$).

Comment: ... as @Meelo said.

Comment: I have to say, even though one only needs the fact that $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing, that's not much of a hint.  After all, $x^2$ is increasing, and $3^2+5^2$ is certainly less than $2^2+6^2$.  A better hint would have been to square the two expressions.  I suppose the fact that $3+5 = 2+6$ suggests that squaring would help, but if you saw that, you probably wouldn't need a hint on the other.

Answer (score 11):

Hint: Easier to show that $$\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}<\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: It seems odd that this answer of mine is the highest-voted answer, since the more straightforward answer is also perhaps more elegant - squaring both sides.

Answer (score 4):

The square-rooting operation on positive numbers is a strictly increasing mapping. That means that if $x^2 < y^2$, you can conclude $x < y$. This is the definition of strictly increasing:

$$a < b \implies f(a) < f(b)$$

By comparing the squares of the numbers instead of the numbers, you *are* using the prompted clue.

Answer (score 3):

Since $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function we have the following
\begin{align*}
2\sqrt{15}&>2\sqrt{12}\\
8+2\sqrt{15}&>8+2\sqrt{12}\\
3+2\sqrt{15}+5&>2+2\sqrt{12}+6\\
(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^2&>(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6})^2
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 2):

Square both sides. You have
$$ \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5} \mathrel{?} \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}.$$
Squaring you get 
$$ 8 + 2\sqrt{15} \mathrel{?} 8 + 2\sqrt{12};$$
paring you get
$$ \sqrt{15} \mathrel{?} \sqrt{12}.$$

Now it is entirely clear.

Comment: The OP knows the solution, his or her question is how to understand the text's prompt.

Comment: You can see that the fact that the square root is increasing on its domain tells all here.

Answer (score 0):

Square the two numbers and we're left to compare $8+2\sqrt{15}$ and $8+2\sqrt{12}$. Because $\sqrt{x}$ is increasing we have

$$\sqrt{12}\lt \sqrt{15}$$

$$8+2\sqrt{12}\lt 8+2\sqrt{15}$$

And therefore

$$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}\lt \sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

The square root function is increasing and concave down (meaning it increases slower and slower as $x$ gets larger).  Thus $\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}>\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{5}$.

Rearranging gives $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}>\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just that $\surd x$ is increasing, it's the *way* that it is increasing.

Although the curve, $y=\surd x$, is increasing monotonically towards the positive infinite as $x$ trends towards the positive infinite, the *slope* of the curve is decreasing monotonically towards zero.  It is concave.

Hence the difference between $\surd 3$ and $\surd 2$ will be larger than the difference between $\surd 6$ and $\surd 5$.

$$\because \surd 3 - \surd 2 > \surd 6-\surd 5 \\[2ex] \therefore \surd 3 + \surd 5 > \surd 2+ \surd 6$$

Comment: In general you are right but we have a very concrete question here.  In this special casse, square both sides and you reduce the question to $\sqrt{15} \stackrel{?}{>} \sqrt{12}$ which can be answered using the given hint.

Answer (score 0):

Putting Graham’s answer into a picture, sort of, which is greater, the combined heights of the green segments or the combined heights of the red segments one unit away in each direction?

[image]